# Cannot access my server after running ifdown eth0

Tags: server

I wanted to restart the restart the network interface on my Centos 6.10 server so I wanted to run `ifdown eth0` and `ifup eth0`, but after running `ifdown eth0` my server crashed and now I cannot access it anymore and all the websites are down.
Please advise what can I do to make it work again. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu does not use eth0. We use predictive names. This is about CENTOS. So we are going to close this: please use a site that is intended for CentOS/Fedora. Solutions we provide are for official Ubuntu and are not always useable on CentOS. See for instance https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server did not crash, but after typing `ifdown eth0` you disconnected it from the network. So you also disconnected yourself from the server and now can't access it.

You need to find a way to access the physical console of the server and run `ifup eth0` from there. Or a way to reboot the server. If your server is a VPS, your VPS provider may provide a "remote KVM" feature in the user panel which will be helpful. Otherwise, examine existing possibilities.

In the future, when restarting network interface, always do it in a single line:

```
ifdown eth0; ifup eth0
```

The server will execute the two commands directly one after the other, so you will disconnect the server from the network, but it will immediately reconnect.